# Compile error when using \bibliography: "can only use in preamble"

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, errors

I have a main file and a `references.bib` file I want to use.

The relevant code in my main file to my file is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
...
\section{References}    

\cite{Heine-Borel}
\cite{L'Hospital}

\bibliography{myBibRefsFile}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

When I try compiling this, I get an error with the `\bibliography` line, telling me it `can only be used in preamble`. Based on the resources I've read, I don't think I'm using it wrong, so why am I getting this error?

Comment: You are mixing biblatex code with older code. With `biblatex` the `\bibliography` command should go in the preamble and you should delete the `\bibliographystyle`. See also the documentation.

Comment: Ulirke is right.  Additionally note that the standard `biblatex` command is actually `\addbibresource{myBibRefsFile.bib}` and thet `\bibliography` is only provided for (partial) backwards compatability.

Answer (score 16):

You use commands for `bibtex` and `.bst` files. The syntax for biblatex should be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myBibRefsFile.bib} % with extension
...
\section{References}    

\cite{Heine-Borel}
\cite{L'Hospital}

\printbibliography
```

The default backend with biblatex is `biber`. If you want to stick to bibtex, specify it as an option to biblatex:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

You also can choose `backend=bibtex8` or `backend=bibtexu`.

Comment: Thank you. I've been looking to install Biber now so I can use \bibliography, \textcite and \parencite. Have you any advice on how to install that?

Comment: Depends on your system. Both MiKTeX and TeX Live/MacTeX have package managers. If you use MiKTeX 64 bit, there's a small problem: there is no biber 64 bit, so you'll have to install the 32 bit version by yourself, in a local texmf tree.

Comment: I think I was working with the 64-bit package, so I'll try and install the 32-bit package now and use that instead. Any advice on what to look out for there?

Comment: The simplest way to go is what I did myself: download `miktext-biber-bin.tar.lzma`. Unzip it, you'll obtain a `texmf` directory. Move the contents of this directory into your LocalTeXMF root (create one if you don't have one yet and validate it with MiKTeX Options). Finally refresh the FNDB.

Comment: Thank you again. The best result I found when searching for a downloadable biber zip file was this one from sourceforge: [http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/]

Is that close to the mark, or do I need exactly that file? If the latter, where might I find it?

Comment: One advantage of MiKTeX's version is that it respects the TDS architecture, so that you don't have to find where to put the doc, the executable, &c. I'm not sure it's the same for Source Forge. You can find MiKTeX package on CTAN, [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages).

Comment: I see. Hopefully last question: where should this LocalTeXMF root folder be? I'm inclined to think somewhere in the /bin folder.

Comment: What's the /bin folder on a Windows system?

Comment: Well there's one pathway such as: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64

Comment: I see. No, your local texmf root must be disjoint the MiKTeX root. You can put its , say, C: \User\Yourname\LocalTeXMF. In this root, you can put all your personal additions to the MiKTeX system.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've created the file and put the biber contents into it. I just need to update the FNDB now and I'm good.
Just been looking for resources at that now, though it seems a little complicated.